# Removing the up and down arrows in TextField of Material UI

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to remove the top down arrows in the textfield of Material UI.

Here is the code:

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
MuiInput: {
  root: {
    "&::-webkit-outer-spin-button, &::-webkit-inner-spin-button": {
      "-webkit-appearance": "none",
      margin: 0
    }
  }
}
})
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: What arrows? Material ui TextField hasn't any arrows

Comment: he means number TextField .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think u should add this lines in your App.css, its easier and cleaner :

```
/* Chrome, Safari, Edge, Opera */
input::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin: 0;
}

/* Firefox */
input[type=number] {
  -moz-appearance: textfield;
}
```

from [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_hide_arrow_number.asp)